# Set the UIImageView of a view controller instance

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am currently trying to set the UImageView of a UIViewController class I defined called MyViewController. In the MyViewController class I have an outlet for the UIImage like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView?
```

I then try to set it in another class by using:

```
let vc:MyViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test") as! MyViewController

   vc.imgView!.image = UIImage(named: "wonders1.png")
```

The problem is imgView is nil when I force unwrap and I'm not sure why since I'm instantiating the view controller

image of my storyboard:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubpQN.png

Error I'm getting:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or describe your storyboard? And also show the uiviewcontroller class in storyboard to make sure you have changed it to your custom class.

Comment: Just added image, everything should be connected to the right class, I also control dragged from the UIImage to the MyViewController class to create the outlet

Comment: When you control dragged from the imageView into MyViewController did the auto-generated code make the imageView optional with a ? or a ! Should be @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView! then you can just use imgView to reference it without unwrapping.

Comment: I redid the connection and left the auto-generated @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView! but I still get the same error as above

Comment: Add a property `UIImage` to `MyViewController`, on `viewDidLoad()`, do `self.imgView!.image = myImageProperty` and do `vc.myImageProperty = UIImage(named:"wonders1.png")`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked I would upvote but its a comment

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add image to an UIImageView instance which isn't initialized yet, the views on UIViewController instance is loaded **only** after `func viewDidLoad()` function gets called (read more on iOS life cycle [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller)).

So in order to complete your task you should implement this inside MyViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   vc.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "wonders1.png")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is the calling class is the only one that knows the name of the image, so I think I will try to find a way to pass the string variable upon initialization of MyViewController EDIT: the comment above solved this for me

Comment: Add image property to the controller and set it and in viewwillappear set your image view with that image property.